Easier way to define JSDoc type hints?
I'd like to use JSDoc type hints as much as possible.
But in some cases, defining hints is tricky.
In this case, it is Svelte's Store.
After much effort, I succeeded with the following code:
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

/** @type{import('svelte/store').Writable<{nick:string, img:string}|null>} */
export const userInfoStore = writable(null);

The above code works perfectly in my VS Code environment.
But it is a bit annoying.
So I also found the following way, with a very, very small overhead:
export const userInfoStore2 = writable((
  (
    /** @type{{nick:string, img:string}|null} */
    val
  ) => val
)(null));

This works perfectly, but I don't like the fact that the actual code is affected, not the comments, just for my convenience.
This is my best.
I tried several codes like the following, but they all failed:
export const userInfoStore3 = writable(
  /** @type{{nick:string, img:string}|null} */
  null
);

/** @type{{nick:string, img:string}|null} */
let userInfoDef4 = null;
export const userInfoStore4 = writable(userInfoDef4);

let userInfoDef5 = null;
export const userInfoStore5 = writable(
  /** @type{{nick:string, img:string}|null} */
  userInfoDef5
);

Any other ideas?

Why is the first version "annoying"?

Svelte is fine, but if it's a data type from another package that the external package indirectly references, I have to do it like this:  /**@type{import('../node_modules/.pnpm/PKG_NAME@0.0.0/node_modules/OTHER_PKG_NAME/build/src/PATH').NAME<{mytype}> */
